# How can i merge 3 dataframe in R

Tags: r, join, merge, dataframe

hi i would like to merge 3 dataframes like that :

```
df1
   A B 
1  1 6 
2  2 7
3  3 8
4  4 9
5  5 1

df2
   C  D 
1  NA NA  
2  NA NA
3  3  8
4  4  9
5  5  1
6  8  9
7  1  2

df3
   E   F 
1  NA NA 
2  NA NA
3  5  6
4  4  9


merged dataframe :

   A  B  C   D  E  F 
1  1  6  NA NA  NA NA
2  2  7  NA NA  NA NA
3  3  8  3  8   NA NA
4  4  9  4  9   NA NA
5  5  1  5  1   NA NA
6  NA NA 8  9   NA NA
7  NA NA 1  2   NA NA
8  NA NA NA NA  5  6
9  NA NA NA NA  4  9
```

the thing is how can i  merge between those 3 dataframes without loosing the values and if there is a function in R who do it because i did a lot of manipulation with the merge function but it did not work
can u help me ,thank you

```
file1 <- paste("C:\\df1.csv")
table1 <- read.table(file1,sep=",",header=T,fill=TRUE)

file2 <- paste("C:\\df2.csv")
table2 <- read.table(file2,sep=",",header=T,fill=TRUE)

file3 <-  paste("C:\\df3.csv")
table3 <- read.table(file3,sep=",",header=T,fill=TRUE)
d2<-table3[5:nrow(table3),]
for(i in 1:4) { d2 <- rbind(rep(NA, ncol(table3)), d2) }
row.names(d2) <- 1:nrow(d2)
d3<-table1[10:nrow(table1),]
for(i in 1:9) { d3 <- rbind(rep(NA, ncol(table1)), d3) }
row.names(d3) <- 1:nrow(d3)


temp_merge <-merge(d3, d2,by=0,  all = TRUE)
temp_merge <- temp_merge[,-1]

final_merge <- merge(table2,temp_merge, by=0, all=TRUE)
row.names(final_merge) <- 1:nrow(final_merge)
final_merge <- final_merge[,-1]
```

Comment: What are the rules for "merging" here?

Comment: `cbind()` can be used to bind data.frames togehter -but this requires them to have the same number of rows. In your example I don't understand why extra `NA`s are added the bottom of df2, but at the top of df3.

Comment: Please show us the code you've tried and explain why it didn’t meet your needs. You seem to merge df1 and df2 by row names (`by = 0`). But the rule for 'adding' df3 is unclear. Were none of the [similar posts on SO helpful?](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[r]+merge+many+several+data+frames). If not, why?

Comment: @Henrik i put my code ,the others posts do not help me because i need to merge 3 dataframe with specific order ,if u see my code d2 is a data frame with has the 4 first rows = NA ,and d3 the first 10 rows=Na ,i do this kind of manipulation to synchronize my data ,so normally when i merge d2 with d3 ,d3 must has NA for the 10 first rows of d2 .A simple merge did not work because my data were merged randomly and i don't understand what's happening ,thank u

Comment: Are you trying to ensure that the row containing (3,8) in d1 aligns with the (3,8) row in d2 (both row 3), and as there is no commonality between the tail of d2 and the head of d3, then d3 should start immediately after d3?  It's a bit confusing, as d2 has already been padded with NAs to achieve this, but not d3, so I'm not certain as to the purpose of the NAs - also you say in your comment d3 has 10 rows of NA - but it only has two rows of NA in the original post

Comment: @GavinKelly the previous post was only an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With: `merge(x, y, by = intersect(names(x), names(y)), all = TRUE)`
all Values are kept and the rows that are just in one Data.frame are filled with NA's.

```
a <- data.frame(a=1:10, b=10:1) 
a <- cbind(rn=1:nrow(a),a) 
c <- data.frame(d=5:15, e=15:5) 
c <- cbind(rn=(1+5):(nrow(c)+5),c) 
d <- data.frame(a=1:3, rn=5:7) 
ac <- merge(a,c, by.x="rn", by.y="rn", all=T) 
acd <- merge(ac,d, by.x="rn", by.y="rn", all=T)
```

Comment: @Jullian ,thank u for your answer but it does not work ,u can see my code  may be there is something wrong

Comment: `by=0` is creating the problems. If you got roindices use them otherwise add them with `cbind`:
`a <- data.frame(a=1:10, b=10:1)
a <- cbind(rn=1:nrow(a),a)
c <- data.frame(d=5:15, e=15:5)
c <- cbind(rn=(1+5):(nrow(c)+5),c)
d <- data.frame(a=1:3, rn=5:7)
ac <- merge(a,c, by.x="rn", by.y="rn", all=T)
acd <- merge(ac,d, by.x="rn", by.y="rn", all=T)`